# double click on .pptx ask every time for default program

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-powerpoint-2013

Using Windows  8.1. When opening a PowerPoint 2013 file double clicking on the file, a dialog shows saying:
How do you want to open this file?
Continue using PowerPoint

And there is a checked check box in "Use this app for all the pptx files"

So, because the check box is checked, it should not ask again, but it does. 
Also, I went to Default Programs and selected all the asociation for PowerPoint, but the problem continues.

The file IS associated with PowerPoint, it shows in the Dialog, what I don't get is why even so it's asking every time!

This DOES NOT happen with Excel or Word files... this files opens inmediatly without asking.

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried right click - open with -> choose default program and then select "Always use the selected program to open this kind of file" if that doesn't work I have another solution.

Comment: Perform a [Repair of Office](https://support.office.com/en-au/article/Repair-an-Office-application-7821d4b6-7c1d-4205-aa0e-a6b40c5bb88b).

Comment: @Ramhound yes I tried, and the same thing, shows the dialog, the checkbox is checked, but asks again next time

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 the office reparation did not solve the problem...

Comment: I will have more time tonight.  I have a solution for you.  Just requires more time than I have at this present time.